# Lost connection Spring Websocket after opening it

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have this WebSocket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

I send Kafka data through SimpMessagingTemplate like this:

```
public class KafkaReceiver {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "metrics", groupId = "metrics")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        MetricRecord m = new MetricRecord(new Long(record.offset()), record.key().toString(), record.value().toString());
        this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/records", m.toString());
    }
}
```

And I have this client:

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/portfolio/records');
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/records', function (message) {
            console.log(message);
            console.log(JSON.parse(message.body));
        });
    });
}
```

When I run this in browser I get the following error:

```
Opening Web Socket...

GET http://localhost:9999/portfolio/records/info?t=1507027267841 404 (Not Found)
r._start @ sockjs.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ sockjs.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
r @ sockjs.min.js:2
r @ sockjs.min.js:3
r @ sockjs.min.js:2
r._getReceiver @ sockjs.min.js:2
r.doXhr @ sockjs.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ sockjs.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
r @ sockjs.min.js:2
r @ sockjs.min.js:2
connect @ metricsApp.js:2
onclick @ VM53 metrics:1

Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:9999/portfolio/records
```

Any thought on that? I could not found a working and different solution than mine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();`

did you try this on your StompEndpoint create?

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

```
var socket = new SockJS('/portfolio/records');
```

You should connect the socket to:

```
var socket = new SockJS('/${YourApplicationContextIfItExists}/${endPoint}')
```

assuming you don't have an application context, it should be

```
var socket = new SockJS('/portfolio')
```

Please note there could be other issues, but I think this might help.